# Find the closure and derived set of $A$ in certain topology.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X=[0,1]\subset\mathbb{R}$, let $\mathscr{B}$ be a basis for the topology $\mathscr{T}_{1}$ on $X$ given by $$\mathscr{B}=\{\{0\},\{1\}\}\cup\{(0,2^{-k})\,:\,k\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge0}\},$$and let $\mathscr{T}_{2}$ be a topology on $X$ given by $$\mathscr{T}_{2}=\left\{G\subset X\,:\,\frac{1}{2}\not\in G\right\}\cup\{G\subset X\,:\,(0,1)\subset G\}.$$If $A=\left\{\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}\right)\right\}$ is a subset of the product space $X^{\ast}=(X,\mathscr{T}_{1})\times(X,\mathscr{T}_{2})$, find the closure $\overline{A}$, and the derived set $A'$ in $X^{\ast}$.

To find $A'$, I looked at the $A=\left\{\frac{1}{4}\right\}\times\{\frac{1}{2}\}$ and using the formula for $A'$ in product space as $A'=\left(\left\{\frac{1}{4}\right\}\times\{\frac{1}{2}\}\right)'=\left(\,\overline{\left\{\frac{1}{4}\right\}}\times\{\frac{1}{2}\}'\right)\cup\left(\left\{\frac{1}{4}\right\}'\times\overline{\{\frac{1}{2}\}}\,\right)=\left(\left[\frac{1}{4},1\right)\times\{\frac{1}{2}\}\right)\cup\left(\left(\frac{1}{4},1\right)\times\{\frac{1}{2}\}\right)=\left[\frac{1}{4},1\right)\times\{\frac{1}{2}\}.$

But, the solution is $A'=\left(\frac{1}{4},1\right)\times\{\frac{1}{2}\}$.

Where am I wrong? or can not use that formula for an one-point subset in the product space?

Comment: The derives set has no easy formula like the closure has, in a product.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, Is it false? ; $(A\times B)'=(\overline{A}\times B')\cup(A'\times\overline{B})$ in product space $X\times Y$, where $A\subseteq X$ and $B\subseteq Y$.

Comment: I’ve never heard of such a formula. Is it part of your text?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, Yes, it is. But, not famous. Also, it might be true only for finite product.

Comment: It probably only is true for finite products indeed. It does bear out, but you miscomputed $\{\frac12\}'$..

Comment: @HennoBrandsma In my first calculation, i have a mistake in calculating $\{\frac{1}{2}\}'$ in $\mathscr{T}_{2}$. Then, the formula deduces the correct solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note first that in any space $X$ and any $x \in X$, $\{x\}'= \overline{\{x\}}\setminus \{x\}$.

So $$\{(\frac14,\frac12)\}' = \overline{\{\frac14\}} \times \overline{\{\frac12\}}\setminus \{(\frac14,\frac12)\} $$

which equals $$[\frac14,1) \times \{\frac12\}\setminus \{(\frac14,\frac12)\} =
(\frac14,1) \times \{\frac12\} $$

as your answer stated it ought to be.

Your computation would have yielded the same result, had you noticed that $\{\frac12\}'=\emptyset$ in $\mathscr{T}_2$ as $\{\frac12\}$ is a closed singleton. Then the first term vanishes.